# Rebase feature from another feature to develop

Tags: git, rebase

Ok, so I am doing a college project, we are using git and we have a rule that every feature uses its own branch and they merge into develop when done. My colleague started a feature branch from another feature branch instead. That feature(feature2) isnt connected with feature1 from where it is branched out Situation:

```
             I    <-feature3
            /
A--B--C----H      <-develop
    \     /
     D---E--F     <-feature1
             \
              G   <-feature2
```

Now I needed stuff from commit G in my feature so i merged it in feature3 before realising that by doing that i would get stuff from commit F too(I tought it was based off develop as it should have been).

```
             I--J   <-feature3
            /   |
A--B--C----H    |   <-develop
    \     /     |
     D---E--F   |   <-feature1
             \ /
              G     <-feature2
```

So now commit J contain commit F and G(Also this graph shows state of origin not just local repo). Is there a way to rebase feature 2 so you get the following graph and that feature 3 loses commit F?

```
              I--J  <-feature3
             /  /
            /  G    <-feature2
           /  /
A--B--C----H-/      <-develop
    \     /      
     D---E--F       <-feature1
```

Also can this changes be pushed to origin?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are describing a cherry-pick. It doesn't do what your final graph does, but then, that graph seems unnecessarily elaborate. A cherry-pick of G does grab the changes from F to G and stick them after J, which sounds like what you are really after.

Comment: Firstly, after J i did couple more commits so I do not know if that influences anything. To me it seem like cherry pick would work if i didnt already merge but now feature 3 contains feature2(commit G) but it also got commit F from feature1. And i want to get rid of commit F not get commit G one more time

Comment: Yes but you can easily just roll back to before the merge.

Comment: In other words, what I'm suggesting is what you _should have done_ in the first place. But this is git, so you can in fact go back in time and _do_ that instead of what you did.

Comment: That does seem like an option, I would have to do Some work to get back to where I was but I could do it. Would rolling back to commit I and pushing change to origin get both origin and my local reko back to first graph?

Comment: Yeah i agree i should have done it if only i realized that feature 2 wasnt based on development

Comment: Well, if you did a bad thing and then pushed, that's _very_ bad. You need to blow the whistle and stop all use of this repo while you fix it. Then you need to create the repo afresh and have your collaborators clone the new version.